React Keybord shortcut triggering twice
I am trying to copy and paste within my div using Keybord. It was triggering twice and I founc the following code triggering twice. How can I solve it?
   useEffect(() => {
        const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === "c") {
                if (selectedRowIndex !== null && explorerContent[selectedRowIndex]) {
                    handleCopy(explorerContent[selectedRowIndex]);
                } else {
                    console.warn("No item selected to copy.");
                }
            }

            if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === "v") {
                handlePasteWithConflictResolution();
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        };
    }, [selectedRowIndex, explorerContent, currentPath, clipboard]);


No item selected to copy. is showing twice here

This question is similar to: React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the development mode, useEffect always runs twice. This is react's inherent behaviour and it does this to check any issues in your application.
